# how to join Between four tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, join

i have 4 tables for mysql database, how i join Between them

users:

```
userid|username
   1  | mark
   2  | jon
```

awards_user :

```
awardid|userid
 1     |1    
 2     |2
```

cat :

```
catid|catname
   1 | english
   2 | computer
```

awards :

```
awardid|catid|awardname|awardlink
 1     |1    |best1    |pic link
 2     |2    |best2    |pic link
```

resulte :

userid|username|catid|catname|awardid|awardname|awardlink

okay , that is my try :

works but Shows only one result, when there is a member holds a award
، I want to show all the awards, even if there is no one holds them .

```
$all_awards = $db->query_read(" SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " users,awards_user,cat,awards
 WHERE
awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid
 AND
awards_user.userid = users.userid
 AND
awards.catid = cat.catid
 ");


CREATE TABLE `awards` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `forumid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `awards`
-- 

INSERT INTO `awards` VALUES (1, 2, 'award one', 'http://www.mwadah.com/pict/noway9.gif');
INSERT INTO `awards` VALUES (2, 1, 'award 2', 'http://www.forum-ksa.com/up/uploads/images/forum-ksac59a7122d1.gif');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `awards_user`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `awards_user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `awardid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `awards_user`
-- 

INSERT INTO `awards_user` VALUES (2, 2, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `forum`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `forum` (
  `forumid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`forumid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `forum`
-- 

INSERT INTO `forum` VALUES (1,'Main Category');
INSERT INTO `forum` VALUES (2,'Main Forum');
-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `user`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `user`
-- 

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'admin');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'mark');
```

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Seeing as you know a `JOIN` is needed, why don't you try to use it first, then show us what you tried, if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your `JOIN` query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN awards_user USING(userid)
JOIN awards USING(awardid)
JOIN cat USING(catid)
```

Then you can add a `WHERE` clause to filter the result.

Comment: it's not work or i write it as wrong `$all_awards = $db->query_read(" SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " user
JOIN awards_user USING(userid)
JOIN awards USING(id)
JOIN forum USING(forumid)
 WHERE
awards_user.awardid = awards.id
 AND
awards_user.userid = user.userid
 AND
awards.forumid = forum.forumid
 "); `

Comment: Maybe you should put that `TABLE_PREFIX` before each table name? And with the form I suggest, you do not need the `WHERE` clause!

Comment: the code don't show me error , but it Shows one result [username,adwordname] only . `TABLE_PREFIX` it's not problem

Comment: You should reproduce your database structure and some content on http://sqlfiddle.com so we can see it

Comment: i cannot add my sql in this site , show me erorr all time , i put it on my first post

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT awards.userid, 
       username, 
       awards.catid, 
       catname, 
       awards.awardid, 
       awardname, 
       awardlink 
FROM   users, 
       awards_user, 
       cat, 
       awards 
WHERE  awards_user.userid = users.userid 
       AND awards_user.awardid = awards.awardid 
       AND cat.catid = awards.catid;
```